# Using RADIUS for host authentication

Tags: authentication, authorization

[Remote Authentication Dial In User Service (RADIUS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) is a networking protocol that provides centralized Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting (AAA) management for computers to connect and use a network service.

My question is can we use RADIUS to authenticate/authorize hosts/servers/nodes which are connecting to the network service (like HTTP) instead of users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, basic client software and server software can be RADIUS clients and can authenticate themselves against RADIUS.

For example, FreeRADIUS server offers the [Apache RADIUS authentication module](http://freeradius.org/mod_auth_radius/) that allows any Apache web-server to become a RADIUS client for authentication and accounting requests.

You can integrate RADIUS client functionality by using **[RADIUSclient framework](http://wiki.freeradius.org/glossary/Radiusclient)** which is a library for writing RADIUS Clients that includes radlogin, a flexible RADIUS aware login replacement, a command line program to send RADIUS accounting records, an utility allowing to send RADIUS AAA requests from command line or from shell scripts and a utility to query the status of a (Merit) RADIUS server. All these programs are based on a library which lets you develop a RADIUS-aware application in less than 50 lines of C code. It is highly portable and runs on Linux, many BSD variants and Solaris.

Answer (score 6):

This is totally dependent on your implementation details. Generally, "yes". For instance, Spring Security, a web application security infrastructure, provides a RADIUS plugin to do Auth/Auth for web applications.

If you are taking system-2-system or machine-2-machine, then again, basically "yes" again. But you will need to come up with a way (certificate, key, etc) to securely store and provide the credentials as you flow from system-2-system and out to the RADIUS server, that prevents clear text or other compromise-able storage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use radius for host authentication.  it's for dial up users.  You might use tacacs.

Comment: [TACACS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TACACS) says

> TACACS+ and RADIUS have generally replaced TACACS and XTACACS in more recently built or updated networks.